# Is there an operation that changes a SharePoint list's GUID to another value?

Tags: list, csom, getchanges

I have a CSOM application that I use to access SharePoint lists.

I have processed a list `https://mysharepoint.shareoint.local/sites/sc123/MyList` with a GUID: `263FE49C-7FB3-4247-93CD-4AAB9770EF97`

Several days later, the same list suddenly has a different GUID `7F1BA68C-8D94-48D7-BF97-AC5C6FF0665A`.

I keep track of List changes using the Changes API but I am probably not handling this particular event.

Are there operations that SharePoint lists can have happen that change the GUID of a list?

What would be the Change API event that would cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no setters on SPList.Id which means it cannot change unless you alter the database directly, which is unsupported.

Comment: so pretty much this means that the list was deleted then recreated then right ?

Comment: Yes, and if you have access to the Content Database, the `EventCache` table would record this.